# initialize mousemove event only after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a plugin that creates a select marquee box when the mouse is clicked on a canvas div. So far i've written the plugin with the `click()` and `mousemove()` events adjacent to each other in the code (i dont know of any way to embed events inside other events). But this becomes a problem when the mouse moves over the canvas before a click. Does anyone know how to initialize a mousemove handler with a click?

Here is the code i have written so far:

```
$.fn.createBox = function(id) {
        $(id).css({
            cursor:'crosshair'
        });

        $(id).click(function(e) {
            var clickLocX = e.pageX;
            var clickLocY = e.pageY;
            $('<div>').attr({
                'class':'newBox',
                'ctr':'on'
            })
            .css({
                top:clickLocY,
                left:clickLocX
            })
            .appendTo(id);
        });
        //Mousemove must be initialized only AFTER the click. HOW TO DO THIS?
        $(id).mousemove(function(e){
            var XpageCoord = e.pageX;
            var YpageCoord = e.pageY;
                window.Xloc = XpageCoord;
                window.Yloc = YpageCoord;
            var boxOffset = $('.newBox').offset();
            var boxHeight = YpageCoord - boxOffset.top; 
            var boxWidth = XpageCoord - boxOffset.left;

            $('.newBox').css({
                height:boxHeight + 'px',
                width:boxWidth + 'px'
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `mousemove` handler from *within* the `click` handler and use a flag to determine whether or not it has already been set to avoid adding it multiple times.

EDIT:  An example

```
assignedMoveHandler = false;
$(id).click(function(e) {
    // other stuff...
    if(!assignedMoveHandler) {
        $(id).mousemove(function(e) {
            // mouse move handling code...                
        });
        assignedMoveHandler = true;
    }
}
```

I use a global here which you may or may not care about, I lookup the jquery object twice, etc., so it could be cleaned up a bit, but this is the general idea.  When the `click` handler fires you check to see if you've assigned a `mousemove` handler yet.  If not, assign it.

Comment: @Ed_S.--Do you mind providing an example of what you mean? it would help a lot.

Comment: @codeninja: Ok, there ya go.  I'm not expert in jquery or web development in general, but the general concept applies here.  Only assign the handler once and only assign it after a click.

Comment: @Ed_S.--Ok, just to clarify: `assignedMoveHandler` is a function? or a jquery object? Could you use a hypothetical example because im still kind of lost...

Comment: @Ed_S.--I made a fiddle of what i have here: http://jsfiddle.net/HYQp4/

Can you tell me what went wrong?